# singleton - trying to initialise a static property on creation fails

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

I  have a singleton class used to initialise error_handling.

The  class as is takes a Zend_Config object and optional $appMode in parameter,  to allow overriding the defined APPMODE constant when testing this class. All is fine if I create the object with non-static properties, but initialising a static property does not work the way I expected when calling  the usual getInstance().

```
class ErrorHandling{

  private static $instance;
  private static $_appMode;  // not initialised in returned instance
  private $_errorConfig;

 private function __construct(Zend_Config $config, $appMode = null){

   $this->_errorConfig = $config;

   if(isset($appMode)){
       static::$_appMode = $appMode;
   }else{
         static::$_appMode = APPMODE;
   }  
 }

 private final function  __clone(){}

 public static function getInstance(Zend_config $config, $appMode = null){
     if(! (static::$instance instanceof self)){
         static::$instance = new static($config, $appMode);
     } 
     return static::$instance;
 }
}
```

Not that I really *need* $_appMode to be static at all, I declared it private and moved on, but  I am still wondering if one can initialise static properties from a static function call. If I REALLY needed static $_appMode, I could probably create the object and set the value afterwards with a  setter method but this doesn't "feel" as being the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout

```
<?

class ErrorHandling{

  private static $instance;
  private static $_appMode;  // not initialised in returned instance
  private $_errorConfig;

 private function __construct(array $config, $appMode = null){

   $this->_errorConfig = $config;

   if(isset($appMode)){
       self::$_appMode = $appMode;
   }else{
         self::$_appMode = APPMODE;
   }  
 }

 private final function  __clone(){}

 public static function getInstance(array $config, $appMode = null){
     if(! (self::$instance instanceof self)){
         self::$instance = new ErrorHandling($config, $appMode);
     } 
     return self::$instance;
 }

 public static function getAppMode() {
    return self::$_appMode;
 }
} 

$e = ErrorHandling::getInstance(array('dev' => true), -255);
var_dump($e, ErrorHandling::getAppMode());
```

Is that your want?

Your could read here about difference between `static` and `self`- [late static binding](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: For some reason I could not set static properties on the singleton in the constructer.

Comment: Thanks,  I had not tried  self::$instance = new ErrorHandling($config, $appMode); I believe I was using self::$instance = new self($config, $appMode); in original code. Also was using static:: for return values and apparently this keyword is only for assignment. Thanks for the feedback ;o)

Comment: @stef `static` is ok for assignment in PHP >= 5.3; it gives slightly different behavior than `self` though.

Comment: @stefgosselin, add link to difference between `self` and `static`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't use any 5.3.x-Version of PHP. "Late Static Binding" (`static::$_appMode`) is not available in any version before. Use `self::$_appMode` instead. Its slightly different from `static`, but in your case it should be OK. For further info read [Manual: Late Static Binding](http://php.net/language.oop5.late-static-bindings)